# action does not call reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I am using react-redux, the problem is that one of my actions does not dispatch to reducer
here is my code:

Actions.js:

```
export const getRooms = () => {
  console.log('reach action')
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: localStorage.getItem('lets_chat_token')
    }
  }
  return dispatch => {
    console.log('in dispatch')
    return axios
      .get(`/api/rooms`, config)
      .then(data =>
        dispatch({
          type: 'GET_ROOMS',
          payload: data.data.data
        })
      )
      .catch(err =>
        dispatch({
          type: 'ERROR',
          payload: err
        })
      )
  }
}
```

I am calling this action in a react component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { getRooms } from '../../Redux/Actions'

import './Connections-list.css'

class ConnectionsList extends Component {
  handleRooms = () => {
    getRooms()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="connections-list-container">
        <div className="connections-list-header">
          <i className="fas fa-users" onClick={this.handleRooms}></i>
          <i className="fas fa-user-friends"> </i>
        </div>
        <div className="connections-list-list">aasa</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(
  null,
  { getRooms }
)(ConnectionsList)
```

The problem is that the first log appears in the getRooms() function:

```
console.log('reach action')
```

But nothing happens after that.

Note: I am using redux-thunk. And I have other actions that works perfectly.

Comment: Can you see the HTTP request being made in the console?

Comment: have you tried [bindActionCreators](https://redux.js.org/api/bindactioncreators) ?

Comment: @Squiggs. the http request does not reach the server. it does not been made

Comment: You need to call binded version of `getRooms` you get from the props `this.props.getRooms()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind you're redux action and then get it in props. Below is modified code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux' // bind redux action with dispatch
import { getRooms } from '../../Redux/Actions'

import './Connections-list.css'

class ConnectionsList extends Component {
  handleRooms = () => {
    const { getRooms } = this.props //get the redux action from props
    getRooms()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="connections-list-container">
        <div className="connections-list-header">
          <i className="fas fa-users" onClick={this.handleRooms}></i>
          <i className="fas fa-user-friends"> </i>
        </div>
        <div className="connections-list-list">aasa</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return bindActionCreators({getRooms}, dispatch)
}

export default connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ConnectionsList)
```

Comment: this works too. but way I should use bindActionCreators here. I mean what is the cases that I should use it

Comment: @M.Amer you rarely need to call `bindActionCreators` manually. `connect` does it for you if you say pass an object as the second argument. Just get the function you call from the component props.

Comment: The only use case for bindActionCreators is when you want to pass some action creators down to a component that isn't aware of Redux, and you don't want to pass dispatch or the Redux store to it.` and for further [reference](https://redux.js.org/api/bindactioncreators)